# How to pass a view to a reusable button

Tags: swiftui

Hey guys I have been getting better with making reusable views, and this is the point that I have reached.

So I would like create a reusable button. The code for it being something like this:

```
let actionCode: () -> ()
let buttonImage: View
```

I also tried some View, also () —> View and similar attempts.

All to be passed to this

```
Button(action: {actionCode})
{buttonImage}
```

Is this possible? Or am I barking up the wrong tree. Also, I did search SO for this

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the description correctly here is a demo of possible approach:

```
struct ReusableView<ButtonImageType: View>: View {
    let actionCode: () -> ()
    let buttonImage: ButtonImageType     // << !!

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: actionCode)
            {buttonImage}
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly it. I haven’t used generics but this is a perfect segue to using it. Thanks

Comment: How would I then pass this into a view as a dependency injection? 

For example, following the example you put in your answer , I would then insert this into my view as a property.  

Like let myButton: ReusableView

I get the error: Reference to generic type ReusableView requires arguments in <> and of course the fix Xcode suggests does not work